# Self-deleted questions display as deleted in an audit

Tags: bug, review, deleted-questions, self-answer, review-audits

[This First Posts review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2237078) is of the answer of a self-answered question, where the question was deleted by the original author.

> [image]

It's really obvious that the question has been deleted and therefore that this is an audit. I couldn't get the full thing into a screen shot but this was *prior* to me successfully<sup>1</sup> passing the review.

I'm not sure that self-deleted questions should not be an audit at all. I understand that only downvoted posts can be audits so it's fair enough in some respects but a user can delete for any number of reasons not necessarily related to the quality of the post.

The answer being audited in this case only has a single downvote.

<sub>1. Woot!</sub>

Comment: Having written all of this I apparently didn't get the audit as I took too long taking screenshots and someone actually failed it...

Comment: This *may* have been chosen because only the question is self-deleted. Technically, the answer was auto-deleted by the *system* because the question was deleted. That may have something to do with the odd selection...